# Is there a way for me to make the circle bounce off the top of the movable object?

Tags: java, object, processing, bounce

Essentially i just want some guidance on how to make the circle bounce off the movable object. Im having trouble and have been trying for three hours and thus have turned to forums for assistance. I have attempted multiple 'if' statements but clearly I am not understanding properly as none are working. Thank you :)

I have been trying for 3 hours to figure this out with different if statements.

```java
float x;
float easing = 1;
float circle_x = 1;
float circle_y = 30;
float rad = 12.5;
float gravity = 0.98;
float move_x = 5;
float move_y = 5;

void setup() {
    size(640, 480);
    frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
    background(#87CEEB);

    fill(#7cfc00);
    rect(0, 430, 640, 80);

    float targetX = mouseX;
    float dx = targetX - x;
    x += dx * easing;

    fill(#000000);
    rect(x, 400, 30, 30);
    rect(x-20, 390, 70, 10);
    rect(x, 430, 5, 20);
    rect(x+25, 430, 5, 20);


    ellipse(circle_x, circle_y, 25, 25);
    circle_x = circle_x + move_x;
    circle_y = circle_y + move_y;

    if (circle_x > width) {
        circle_x = width;
        move_x = -move_x;
    }

    if (circle_y > height) {
        circle_y = height;
        move_y = -move_y;
    }

    if (circle_x < 0) {
        circle_x = 0;
        move_x = -move_x;
    }

    if (circle_y < 0) {
        circle_y = 0;
        move_y= -move_y;
    }
}
```

Inserting any variables into if statements and only receiving back: the ball being bounced by my mouse cursor (not the object), glitchy circles and stuttery images.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection in Processing.

Comment: No harm in some promo, I will definitely save that link and appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be checked if the x coordinate of the ball is in the range of the object ( `objW` is the width of the object):

```java
circle_x > x && circle_x < x + objW
```

and if the y coordinate of the ball has *reached* the level of the object (`objH` is the level of the object and `circleR` is the radius of the ball):

```java
circle_y > objH - circleR
```

Further it is important to do the hit test first and to do the  test if the object bounce the ground after. A good style is to do this in an `else if` statement:

```java
int objX1 = -20;
int objX2 = 70;
int objH = 390;
int circleR = 25/2;
if (circle_x > x + objX1  && circle_x < x + objX2 && circle_y > objH - circleR ) {
    circle_y = objH-circleR;
    move_y = -move_y; 
}
else if (circle_y > height) {
    circle_y = height;
    move_y = -move_y;
}
else if (circle_y < 0) {
    circle_y = 0;
    move_y= -move_y;
}
```

Further I recommend to calculate the position of the ball first and then draw the ball at ist current position:

[image]

```java
float x;
float easing = 1;
float circle_x = 1;
float circle_y = 30;
float rad = 12.5;
float gravity = 0.98;
float move_x = 5;
float move_y = 5;

void setup() {
    size(640, 480);
    frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
    background(#87CEEB);

    fill(#7cfc00);
    rect(0, 430, 640, 80);

    float targetX = mouseX;
    float dx = targetX - x;
    x += dx * easing;

    circle_x = circle_x + move_x;
    circle_y = circle_y + move_y;
    if (circle_x > width) {
        circle_x = width;
        move_x = -move_x;
    }
    else if (circle_x < 0) {
        circle_x = 0;
        move_x = -move_x;
    }

    int objW = 70;
    int objH = 390;
    int circleR = 25/2;
    if (circle_x > x && circle_x < x + objW && circle_y > objH-circleR ) {
        circle_y = objH-circleR;
        move_y = -move_y; 
    }
    else if (circle_y > height) {
        circle_y = height;
        move_y = -move_y;
    }
    else if (circle_y < 0) {
        circle_y = 0;
        move_y= -move_y;
    }

    fill(#000000);
    rect(x, 400, 30, 30);
    rect(x-20, 390, 70, 10);
    rect(x, 430, 5, 20);
    rect(x+25, 430, 5, 20);

    ellipse(circle_x, circle_y, 25, 25);
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the extent of help you went to :) You have greatly assisted me and I thank you for it. I used your advice as guidance and fortunately it now works so thank you very much